# Predicates that look like negation to each other.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Is it possible, that both sentences are simultaneously true?

1. All cars are white.
2. All cars are black.

My take is yes, because second sentence is not a negation of the first one, so no contradiction, but not sure.

Comment: If there are no cars, then both statements are vacuously true.  If there is even a single car, then the statements are incompatible.

Comment: $x=1$ is not the negation of $x=1$, but they cannot both be true, because $x=1$ **implies** $x\ne 0$, the negation of $x=0$. As **lulu** points out, your situation is a little more complicated, but that is only because of the universal quantifier, which makes both statements vacuously true if there are no cars.

Comment: It has to do with "white" and "black" being exclusive to each other, an information one would implicitly use without annoucing it. But instead of "black" use "flying" then there will be no  contradiction.

Comment: A model in which the extension of 'cat' is non-empty cannot satisfy both sentences. However such a model can satisfy the negations of both sentences; simply take a model where the interpretation of 'cat' is neither a subset of the white things nor of the black things (wrt to the model).

Comment: There's also a question of whether a car can be both black and white (I would say yes!).